# Gson: @Expose vs @SerializedName

Tags: java, android, json, gson

With respect to Gson what is the difference between  `@Expose` and `@SerializedName("stringValue")`?

Comment: @MarkKeen, hey mate the link is broken.

Comment: updated link (another google search) http://websystique.com/java/json/gson-json-annotations-example/

Comment: The default value will be true If we don't specify any value to the Expose annotation.

Answer (score 240, accepted):

Even if it's late I wanted to answer this question.
To explain it we must know what is `serialization` and `deserialization`.
`serialization` is converting `object` into `json string` and `deserialization` is converting `json string` into `object`.

Let's say we've `User` class with no annotations.

```
public class User{
    private String userName;
    private Integer userAge;

    public User(String name, Integer age){
        userName = name;
        userAge = age;
    }
}
```

And we `serialize` this `object` as below

```
User user = new User("Ahmed", 30);
Gson gson = new Gson();
String jsonString = gson.toJson(user);
```

Json string will be like this

```
{
    "userName":"Ahmed",
    "userAge":30
}
```

If we add annotation `@SerializedName`

```
public class User{

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String userName;
    @SerializedName("age")
    private Integer userAge;

    public User(String name, Integer age){
        userName = name;
        userAge = age;
    }
}
```

Json string will be like this

```
{
    "name":"Ahmed",
    "age":30
}
```

`@Expose` is used to allow or disallow `serialization` and `deserialization`.
`@Expose` is optional and it has two configuration parameters: `serialize` and `deserialize`. By default they're set to true.
To `serialize` and `deserialize` with `@Expose` we create gson object like this

```
Gson gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder().excludeFieldsWithoutExposeAnnotation().create();
```

Below `userName` won't be deserialized. userName's value will be `null`.

```
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose(deserialize = false)
private String userName;
```

Below `userName` won't be serialized.

```
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose(serialize = false)
private String userName;
```

Json string will be like this. Only `userAge` will be deserialized.

```
{
    "age":30
}
```

Comment: @Kwnstantinos Happy to help you !

Comment: Thank you. When we set serialization to false, after serialization we'll not see out username in json string. But one moment. Let's assume we set username deserialization to false. So when we will deserialize our json, we'll get username null. Am I right?

Comment: @Bek: Lovely explanation

Comment: The default value will be true If we don't specify any value to the Expose annotation.

Comment: can we change `serialization` value during runtime?

Answer (score 95):

`@SerializeName` is used to set the key that json object will include ,however `@Expose` is used to decide whether the variable will be exposed for Serialisation and Deserialisation ,or not. [Here's](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.code.gson/gson/2.6.2/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.html) the documentation of `@Expose`.

Comment: What if we had both `Expose` and `SerializeName`?

Comment: ```Expose``` is using in rare cases and It can be removed

Comment: @HamzehSoboh then it will depend upon the  values passed in `@Expose`. (its complete syntax is `@Expose(serialize = <true/false>,deserialize = <true/false>)` , where true is default for both.

Answer (score 13):

```
class Person{
String name;
String password;
}
```

suppose if i put i annotation **Expose** on top of a variable name or password without **SerializedName**, it will be serialized AS variable name

But if we put **SerializedName** like ("**username**") or ("**password**"),they will be serialized with that key

if Serialized

```
{"username":"trinadh","password":"hello"}
```

if not

```
{"name":"trinadh","password":"hello"}
```

Answer (score 5):

Moreover, [`@Expose` comes with two boolean flags](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/annotations/Expose.java): `deserialize` and `serialize`, to allow skipping the field for one phase.