# How to parsing this json to gson in retrofit

Tags: android, json, gson, retrofit

I'm trying to convert a JSON to GSON
I'm not sure this is the best structure.

All responses consist of code, msg, and data structure.
But the internal structure of data can vary.

Do I have to create a response object even if there is only one value in the data like this?

If you know a better way than this, please advise me.
thank you :)

```
{
"code": "000",
"msg": "okay",
"data": {
    "myCartCount": "0"
}
}
```

this is my reponse object

```
public class BaseResponse{
  public String code;
  public String msg;
}

public class MyCartResponse extends BaseResponse{
   @SerializedName("data")
   public MyCart myCart;
}

public class MyCart{
  @SerializedName("myCartCount")
  public String count;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this annotation `@SerializedName` and `@Expose`

```
public class BaseResponse{
  @SerializedName("code")
  @Expose
  public String code;
  @SerializedName("msg")
  @Expose
  public String msg;

   @SerializedName("data")
   @Expose
   public MyCartResponse myCart;
}

public class MyCartResponse {
  @SerializedName("myCartCount")
  public String count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! :) , can you explain why I use @Expose?

Comment: Good answer link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34752200/gson-expose-vs-serializedname